# Corollary of limit existence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Must be tried:

> Suppose that $A\subseteq\mathbb R$, $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is an accumulation point of $A$. Then $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ does not exist if there is a divergent sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $A$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n}=c$.

I have problems with this corollary. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: You want $c\in A$, not $c\in R$, right? Also: is $f$ supposed to be continuous?

Comment: You should explain your problem with the corollary

Comment: You are saying, $(x_n)$ is divergent,but then you write, $lim_{n \to\infty} x_n = c $, that is meaningless. Please describe your problem properly.

Comment: Please edit. I think you mean there is a divergent sequence $(f(x_n))_{n\in \Bbb N}.$